# How to count the number of people selecting one option in Swift UI using Cloud Firebase?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have 2 option in my FirstView. After that user chooses "good" or "bad". Then user chooses city and district that he/she lives in from the pickerview in SecondView. My aim is to show the number of people who selected "good" and the number of people who selected "bad" in user's region in ThirdView. I can get the city and district names and store in database but I don't know how to create a logic for counting the number of people in the selected area. My firebase side is as follows...[image]
I want ThirdView to look like
[image]

```
struct Lokasyon: Identifiable, Codable {
var id : String
var cityName: String
var districtName: String
var okeyButton : Bool
}

class TakeViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var lokasyon = [Lokasyon]()

private var db = Firestore.firestore()
private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?

deinit {
    unsubscribe()
}

func unsubscribe() {
    if listenerRegistration != nil {
        listenerRegistration?.remove()
        listenerRegistration = nil
    }
}

func subscribe() {
    unsubscribe()
    if listenerRegistration == nil {
        listenerRegistration = db.collection("posts").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            
                 self.lokasyon = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
                    
                 return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Lokasyon.self)

            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

}

struct ThirdView: View {

@ObservedObject var something = TakeViewModel()

var body: some View {
    
    
    VStack{
        
        VStack(spacing: 25){
            Text("How others feel in")
            
            ForEach(something.lokasyon){i in
                
                VStack{
                
                    Text(i.cityName)
                    
                    Text(i.districtName)
                }
            }
           
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    Image("smile")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Text("587")
                    Text("Feeling Good")
                }
                
                VStack{
                    Image("sad")
                        .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Text("235")
                    Text("Feeling Bad")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: self.something.subscribe)
}
}
```

I wrote the numbers by hand just to give an idea and show how my final view looks like.

Answer (score 1):

With your current data structure, you'll need to run a query to get the documents for the region, and then count the number of positive and negative responses with client-side code.

This requires that you read all document from the region. So as you add more users, you'll have have more users for each region, and each of them will be reading the documents for everyone in that region. This will lead to an exponential increase in the number of documents that you read, and thus the cost of using Firestore.

The better approach is to store the counter values themselves into the database, and then update them on each relevant write operation. For example, you could have a single document for each reason where you keep the count of positive and negative responses, and then update that when someone casts a vote.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) and [distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

Comment: Sir, thank you for quick response. I still can not figure out the way to count city wise. Let's say I create a document for only numbers of good or bad responses. How should I know that the vote user's choose corresponds to that city selection in different documents. If you'd like to see all of my codes are in the link. https://github.com/ozanones/firestoredeneme

Comment: If your question is about how to secure the count, that is a different question. There are multiple ways to do that (Cloud Functions, security rules), which are covered in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation too.

Comment: No, it's not about security relations. I'm having difficulty finding a proper path to count the number of selections in that city and district. I can not think any different way other than listing all the city and district names and then count but this is so much work and impossible to deal with. I'm sure there is an easy way to achieve this. I'm also using Swift UI and MVVM structure which is also complicated as I'm beginner in this area.

Comment: If you want to efficiently retrieve the count of a certain vote types for certain locations, you'll need to store the count per vote type per location, there is no way around that with Firestore. There's not much more I can say about that. If you think that is too much work, you might want to consider using a database that is better at handling ad-hoc queries, like most SQL or GraphQL based databases.